# Angle between a vector and a subspace on infinite dimensional Hilbertspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let be $X$ a Hilbertspace and $0\not\equiv L:X\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous linear function. I like to compute the angle $\alpha$ between a vector $x\in X$ and the kernel of $L$. If $dim X<\infty$, then it is easy. By using Riesz representation theorem, we get $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{|Lx|}{\|L\|\cdot\|x\|}$.

I'd like to know if this holds also when $dim X=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riez Theorem holds in any Hilbert space. So your argument is valid even if $X$ has infinite dimension.